# sys.process to wrap a process as a function

Tags: scala

I have an external process that I would like to treat as a
function from `String=>String`.  Given a line of input, it will respond with a single line of output.  It seems that I should use
scala.sys.process, which is clearly an elegant library that makes many
shell operations easily accessible from within scala.  However, I
can't figure out how to perform this simple use case.

If I write a single line to the process' stdin, it prints the result
in a single line.  How can I use `sys.process` to create a wrapper so I
can use the process interactively?  For example, if I had an
implementation for `ProcessWrapper`, here is a program and it's output:

```
// abstract definition
class ProcessWrapper(executable: String) {
  def apply(line: String): String
}

// program using an implementation
val process = new ProcessWrapper("cat -b")
println(process("foo"))
println(process("bar"))
println(process("baz"))
```

Output:

```
 1  foo
 2  bar
 3  baz
```

It is important that the process is not reloaded for each call to `process` because there is a significant initialization step.

Comment: I understand what you want, but that really works only for `cat -b` I guess - the problem is, that your apply is called synchronously and should return a string. Now consider a command that returns several lines and takes - say - a second to execute. How will apply know when processing is finished and enough lines were collected? You should think about an asynchronous solution - either with a simple line-listener (that gets each line from the process) or using Akka actors - and rephrase your question. The synchronous solution won't work - except when you always get a single line calling apply.

Comment: Sigh, I think the problem would also happen with commands that output a single line response for each input due to irregular flushing.

Comment: I rewrote some of my java-code for scala - now with the listener. See if you like it :). I still have a more refined approach in java, even support process priority - but the latter for windows only. Would actually be interesting to port it to Scala and Linux/OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So - after my comment - this would be my solution

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader

import scala.annotation.tailrec

class ProcessWrapper(cmdLine: String, lineListenerOut: String => Unit, lineListenerErr: String => Unit,
                     finishHandler: => Unit,
                     lineMode: Boolean = true, envp: Array[String] = null, dir: File = null) {

  class StreamRunnable(val stream: InputStream, listener: String => Unit) extends Runnable {
    def run() {
      try {
        val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.stream));
        @tailrec
        def readLines {
          val line = in.readLine
          if (line != null) {
            listener(line)
            readLines
          }
        }
        readLines
      }
      finally {
        this.stream.close
        finishHandler
      }
    }
  }
  val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine, envp, dir);
  val outThread = new Thread(new StreamRunnable(process.getInputStream, lineListenerOut), "StreamHandlerOut")
  val errThread = new Thread(new StreamRunnable(process.getErrorStream, lineListenerErr), "StreamHandlerErr")
  val sendToProcess = process.getOutputStream
  outThread.start
  errThread.start

  def apply(txt: String) {
    sendToProcess.write(txt.getBytes)
    if (lineMode)
      sendToProcess.write('\n')
    sendToProcess.flush
  }

}

object ProcessWrapper {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val process = new ProcessWrapper("python -i", txt => println("py> " + txt),
      err => System.err.println("py err> " + err), System.exit(0))
    while (true) {
      process(readLine)
    }
  }
}
```

The main part is the StreamRunnable, where the process is read in a thread and the received line is passed on to a "LineListener" (a simple String => Unit - function).
The main is just a sample implementation - calling python ;)

Comment: actually the `while(true)` and `exit` is really just a sample. When remote-executing another command you would normally do the processing within the output handlers and just recognize internally when the process has finished (not calling exit).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you want somethings like that ?

```
  case class ProcessWrapper(executable: String) {
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
    import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    lazy val process = sys.runtime.exec(executable)

    def apply(line: String, blockedRead: Boolean = true): String = {
      process.getOutputStream().write(line.getBytes())
      process.getOutputStream().flush()
      val r = new ByteArrayOutputStream
      if (blockedRead) {
        r.write(process.getInputStream().read())
      }
      while (process.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
        r.write(process.getInputStream().read())
      }
      r.toString()
    }

    def close() = process.destroy()
  }

  val process = ProcessWrapper("cat -b")

  println(process("foo\n"))
  println(process("bar\n"))
  println(process("baz\n"))
  println(process("buz\n"))
  println(process("puz\n"))

  process.close
```

Result :

> ```
>  1    foo
>
>  2    bar
>
>  3    baz
>
>  4    buz
>
>  5    puz
> ```

I think that [PlayCLI](https://github.com/gre/playCLI) is a better way.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something like this.  Ideally I would use the scala executable library but it's not obvious how to do so.

Comment: It's looking more and more that PlayCLI *is* what I want.  I'll have a closer look.

Comment: I'd like the class methods I described and I'm not sure how to do this with PlayCLI since it involves mingling mutation with iteratees.

Comment: why would you want to use ProcessIO ?

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.greweb.fr/2013/01/playcli-play-iteratees-unix-pipe/ came across this today and looks exactly like what you want

Comment: It looks like a layer on top of `ProcessIO` to make piping easier.  I *hope* that what I want is a simple use case, but the lack of response to my questions is making me reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an Akka actor. The actor can have state and thus a reference to an open program (in a thread). You can send messages to that actor.

ProcessWrapper might be a typed actor itself or just something that converts the calls of a function to a call of an actor. If you only have 'process' as method name, then `wrapper ! "message"` would be enough.

Having a program open and ready to receive commands sounds like an actor that receives messages.

Comment: Would you use the Java or the Scala interface to the process within the actor?

Comment: I would probably use a Scala interface

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Probably I got the requirements wrong. You want to send multiple lines to the same process. That's not possible with the below solution.

One possibility would be to add an extension method to the `ProcessBuilder` that allows for taking the input from a string:

```
implicit class ProcessBuilderWithStringInput(val builder: ProcessBuilder) extends AnyVal {
  // TODO: could use an implicit for the character set
  def #<<(s: String) = builder.#<(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes))
}
```

You can now use the method like this:

```
scala> ("bc":ProcessBuilder).#<<("3 + 4\n").!!
res9: String = 
"7
"
```

Note that the type annotation is necessary, because we need two conversions (`String` -> `ProcessBuilder` -> `ProcessBuilderWithStringInput`, and Scala will only apply one conversion automatically.

Comment: Yes, I do want to send multiple lines to the same process.  There is a significant initialization step when the process is first loaded.  However, I don't have all the data to send to the process at once.